# Modifying the object result in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and it would be much appreciated if I could get some expertise assistance with a script that I'm trying to write in PowerShell.

**Objective**:
Run a script to remotely check the name of the current user who is logged on to that machine.

Current script:

This line with the variable of `$EnterComputerName` prompts us to input in what computer name we want to search.

```bsh
$EnterComputerName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Computer name"
```

This line searches the details from that specified computer and pipe it so that it will only show the `Username` property.

```bsh
$Name = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $EnterComputerName | Select-Object Username
```

**Problem:**
The result of the above line only outputs the user ID instead of their actual name, example: `domain\N12345`

I want to use the following line to convert `userID` into name:

```bsh
Get-ADUser $Name | Select-Object GivenName, Surname
```

However, `Get-ADUser` only recognizes `'N23705'` instead of `'domain\N23705'`. Is there a way I can shorten this to `'N23705'` and pass that value to the `$Name` variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pull NT user ID from powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693818/pull-nt-user-id-from-powershell) or [Store username of system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20749920/150605)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to accomplish this is to use replace to remove the unwanted domain prefix.

```
$Name = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $EnterComputerName).UserName -replace ".*\\", ""
```

Edit: removed Parenthesis in replace syntax

Comment: That worked! Thanks Adam!